# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `' for #<User:0x50987b8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

This is a really simple problem I believe.

users_controller

```
def testcall
end
```

routes

```
resources :users
```

In console I type

```
a = User.new
a.testcall
```

I've tried making it

```
self.testcall
```

and then calling

```
User.testcall
```

and its the same issue

Comment: It looks like you are adding methods to `UserController` but are expecting it in `User`?

Comment: You are right. How would I write a command that was just for one user. The way I got it to work is by writing it as passing in a specific user to the controller, but is there another way?

Comment: If you write without `self` the method will be instance method specific for a user instance.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a call like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses the model-view-controller pattern, meaning the model, in this case `User`, and its internal behaviors are separated from the controller, in this case `UsersController`. The convention is to have "fat" models and "skinny" controllers, meaning most of the code defining behaviors is in the model.

So, if you want the behavior to be for an instance of `User`, that behavior should be inside the `User` class (which should be in `app/models/user.rb`).

For instance:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def testcall
      puts "This is a test"
    end
end
```

Then you could call this from the rails console like you were doing. This is because you are bypassing the controller and calling methods directly on the model by calling:

```
a = User.new
a.testcall
```

in the console. If you actually want this to be performed when someone visits a webpage, submits a form, or whatever, then you must assign the appropriate request action in the controller to call the method on a designated instance of `User`.

For example,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @user = User.new
        @user.testcall
    end
 end
```

Obviously, the routes must be properly set up for that to work.

Comment: Thanks. Perfect explanation